# Visual Studio 2017 Community will not start on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6, visual-studio-community

Visual Studio 2017 Community will not start on my Windows 10 Pro machine saying:

> .NET Framework 4.6 is not installed.

The issue is, **.NET Framework 4.6** is installed, and no amount of reinstalling, restarting, reinstalling and restarting will make any part of Windows recognize this fact. What in the world is going on here?

I'm using Windows 10 Creator's Update, and for some forsaken reason that means that I can apparently *never* install **.NET Framework < 4.7** manually, and nothing I can do or google my way to seems to reflect this issue or provide a solution. I've also tried repairing my VS install several times with the VS installer, no dice.

[image: The error message]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the error message that occurs.

Comment: Did you try starting VS as Administrator?

Comment: I'm using VS2017 community and on Windows 10 Pro, I'll edit my original question to include this information

Comment: What does Repair do or not do?  Why can't you install 4.6?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Repair does nothing, seemingly. Additionally Windows will not allow installing a lower version of .NET if a higher one exists, and apparently Windows Creator's Update has .NET 4.7 integrated.

Comment: @Isma I'm sorry to hear that, as it's entirely impeding my ability to use a basic IDE for development, and of course the "official" channel for troubleshooting is entirely useless. I'm certain finding an answer to this issue would be helpful to many.

Comment: @TroelsJessen waiting for your edit...

Comment: @Asif.Ali I have already edited the question, adding some more details and a picture of the error message. Is there anything further that might help?

Comment: @Asif.Ali If you'll read the question I posted, it now says "Visual Studio 2017 **Community** will not start on my Windows 10 **Pro** machine saying"

Comment: @TroelsJessen sorry! I have not seen that line.

Comment: @TroelsJessen try installing .Net framework 4.6 **offline version** and download from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48137

Comment: @Asif.Ali I moved this conversation to chat.

Comment: If your system is corrupted, you can try to reinstall Windows...

Comment: @Phil1970 Sort of a drastic measure, and no I doubt my entire system is corrupted. What's way more likely is that something in VS2017 and/or the .NET Framework is giving a false negative or wound up in some sorta state where it can't use 4.6 features even though 4.7 is installed and .NET is backwards compatible (hence why you can't install an older version on a system that has a newer version already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can fix the error in the registry and avoid the work-around of changing PKGDEF file (which will be removed once there's an update to VS)

- Using regedit.exe, please check if value HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version is set to 4.7.02046 or larger
- Please set value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version to the same value (it is 4.0.* at the moment). You may need to take ownership of the key.

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/113984/net-framework-46-is-not-installed.html?childToView=114302#comment-114302

Comment: @Asif.Ali What edits could I possibly do, all I'm doing is restating a workaround provided to me